# Highcharts spline dataLabels overlapping

Tags: highcharts, overlapping, spline

I have a question about highchart's overlapping data labels. I have 2 spline data series and as you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/3E8V4/ some data labels are overlapping.

Question here is: is this overlapping even possible to prevent? If yes - how should I do it?

Code for plotoptions is like that:

```
plotOptions: {
            spline: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: 'True',
                    crop: false,
                    overflow: 'none'
                },
                enableMouseTracking: false
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use that plugin for repositioning dataLabels: http://jsfiddle.net/menXU/1/ It's not perfect, since works only for max 2 series and requires disabled animations, or you will see little delay when repositioning dataLabels.

How to use? Copy `StaggerDataLabels` and `isLabelOnLabel` functions, and then use `StaggerDataLabels` in load and redraw events for chart.

Answer (score 0):

Sobis,

I don't have a answer that is exactly what you are expecting.

In this case what i would do is increase the max of yAxis by 10% of the maxi m of the data.
provide zoom in/out. that will enable the user to get a values on top of the points

```
zoomType: 'xy'
```

here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/3E8V4/1/

hope you will find it useful

Comment: I would like on the 2., 3. and 5. serie data that one of the spline's would have data label above itself, and one below. On the second node for example in that case the value 70 would be below blue line, and 73,33 above (like now). In the fifth node it would be vice versa - black 98.31 below and blue above. So that data labels wouldn't overlap and it would be clear to see.