# Highcharts position dataLabels on hide/show event

Tags: highcharts, hide, show

**Our purpose:** We are working on a function that avoids overlapping dataLabels by repositioning. Doing so we are facing problems when updating the dataLabel position by the show event. To illustrate our problem we included a simplified example with a function that repositions the first dataLabel of each visible series by 30px to the top (y-direction). The reposition-function is fired by the show event.

```
... function adjustLables(chart, visibleIndex) {
console.log('dataLabels');
for (var i = 0; i < visibleIndex.length; i++) {

    var index = visibleIndex[i],
        dataLabel = chart.series[index].points[0].dataLabel,
        adjY = dataLabel.y - 30;

    chart.series[index].points[0].dataLabel.attr({
        y: adjY
    });
    console.log(chart.series[index].name, 'dataLabel.y:', dataLabel.y, ', adjY:', adjY, dataLabel);

};
console.log('\n');
}; ...
```

**Our problem:**
Although our function adjusts the dataLabel.y property by applying .attr({y: adjY}), the dataLabel object does not behave in the way we expected.

For example: (**[see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pbNfz/)** and the following description)

1. The repositioning works only once for a series that is shown by clicking the legend item for the first time. If one decativates and activates the same series again our adjustment does not work any longer. 
   (e.g. Activate series2 in our fiddle and you will see that its first dataLabel is moved 30px to the top. However, deactivate / reactivate series2 and the dataLabel is no longer moved 30px to the top but appears at its standard position.)
2. For debugging this mysterious deactivate/activate behavior we logged some information to the console after .attr() is called: seriesName, dataLabel.y, adjY, dataLabel-object. Surprisingly, although the dataLabel.y and adjY values are the same the dataLabel object itself remains unaffected at its y-property.

Overall we are wondering whether the show event is the proper way to "update" the dataLabel positions. Any experience or suggestions are very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is caused mainly by `animations`, disable it for debugging: http://jsfiddle.net/pbNfz/1/ - works better now.

Also, see this very [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044479/highcharts-spline-datalabels-overlaping/20050449).