# Overlap datalabels line chart highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, overlap, linechart

How i can solve the problem of the values (dataLabels) ​​below?
[image]

My JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3kVJS/3/

```
 ...
     series: [{
         name: 'zzzzzz',
         data: [17.00, 1.00, 5.00, 0.00, 0.00, 35.00, 6.00, 13.00, 233.00, 2.00, 41.00],
         tooltip: {
             shared: true,
             useHTML: true,
             showInLegend: false,
             pointFormat: '<span style=\"color:{series.color}; text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ddd;\">{series.name}</span>: <span style=\"font-size:14px!important\"> {point.y}</span><br/>'
         }
     }
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Highcharts doesn't prevent from dataLabels overlapping. I have created simple module which prevent's from this, see simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/menXU/1/

Use module by calling `StaggerDataLabels(series);`, where series is array of all series in chart object.

In the fact it's duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044479/highcharts-spline-datalabels-overlaping/20050449), but I couldn't report this.

Comment: Hi, @PawelFus!

I'm using your module, however as i am generating an image of this chart with the phantomjs, the module is not working. 
Many thanks for the help!

Comment: Just added exporting to my demo, works fine, see: http://jsfiddle.net/menXU/9/ Make sure you are using Highcharts 3.0.10

Answer (score 4):

Just add this inside tooltips you will get it what to do.

tooltip: {
            style: {
                padding: 20,
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                fontSize: '30px',
            }
        },

Answer (score 0):

Hai Just add `verticalAlign: 'bottom',` instead of using `verticalAlign: 'top',` at the `plotOptions`.