# Highcharts bar chart datalabels overlap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, charts, highcharts

I'm using  highcharts bar chart.The Series is dynamically loaded so there can be sometime only one value and some times 10 values.I can't give a set width.I m having an issue where The datalabels on the top of bar chart is overlapping with each other when there are lot of values. After doing research on internet the closest thing I could find for this issue is on stackflow which is for two or more series

[Overlap datalabels line chart highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22671871/overlap-datalabels-line-chart-highcharts)

Is there any way we can detect the overlap for a single series and adjust the datalabel so it is not overlapping with each other.
Thanks for any kind of help

Comment: You could rotate the datalables. http://jsfiddle.net/w7cc8krc/

Answer (score 0):

In general this solution is not supported, but you adapt this workaround

```
    function StaggerDataLabels(series) {
    sc = series.length;
    if (sc < 2) return;

    for (s = 1; s < sc; s++) {
        var s1 = series[s - 1].points,
            s2 = series[s].points,
            l = s1.length,
            diff, h;

        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            if (s1[i].dataLabel && s2[i].dataLabel) {
                diff = s1[i].dataLabel.y - s2[i].dataLabel.y;
                h = s1[i].dataLabel.height + 2;

                if (isLabelOnLabel(s1[i].dataLabel, s2[i].dataLabel)) {
                    if (diff < 0) s1[i].dataLabel.translate(s1[i].dataLabel.translateX, s1[i].dataLabel.translateY - (h + diff));
                    else s2[i].dataLabel.translate(s2[i].dataLabel.translateX, s2[i].dataLabel.translateY - (h - diff));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//compares two datalabels and returns true if they overlap


function isLabelOnLabel(a, b) {
    var al = a.x - (a.width / 2);
    var ar = a.x + (a.width / 2);
    var bl = b.x - (b.width / 2);
    var br = b.x + (b.width / 2);

    var at = a.y;
    var ab = a.y + a.height;
    var bt = b.y;
    var bb = b.y + b.height;

    if (bl > ar || br < al) {
        return false;
    } //overlap not possible
    if (bt > ab || bb < at) {
        return false;
    } //overlap not possible
    if (bl > al && bl < ar) {
        return true;
    }
    if (br > al && br < ar) {
        return true;
    }

    if (bt > at && bt < ab) {
        return true;
    }
    if (bb > at && bb < ab) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/menXU/6/.

Comment: How can I use this for single series .... the rotation trick is not really working good for me.....By doing rotation the right most label is not getting displayed... is there any way we can detect the label overlap for single series and align it