# column highchart overlapping and axis X line issue

Tags: highcharts, overlapping

I am trying to use highchart to draw a column chart (as you can see in jsfiddle example).

http://jsfiddle.net/md2zk/48/`my jsfiddle example`

However, I face two problems:

1 data overlapping. The image width is fixed, but the data values are dynamic. If the data is close, it will overlap each other. Is there a way to solve this?

2. I want to show a line as the attched png file. However, seems can't find a way to do it.
   [image]

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

1.) Simple answer is to just rotate the labels:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        dataLabels: {
            rotation: 290,
            y: -32,
            x: 10
        }
    },
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/md2zk/49/).  If you want to get fancier, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20050449/16363) by @PawelFul.

2.) To add a yAxis line, set [yAxis.lineWidth > 0](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.lineWidth):

```
yAxis: {
    lineWidth: 1,
```

See updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/md2zk/52/).

Comment: Hi Mark, The X coordinate of  line needs to be at the start of X Axis. How can that be achieved?

Comment: @daxu, I misunderstood what you were after, see updated answer to add yAxis line.

Comment: great. That is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

For the line series, you just need to add another series, with  `type:'line'`

example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/md2zk/50/

{{edit to address comments:

if you want the line series to start at the Y axis line, you need to use a second x axis, and assign the data series to that axis.  categorical axes will not start the data point at the edge of the chart.

}}

For the overlapping data labels, there is no out of the box solution to avoid collision for these elements.
There are a number of feature requests that may be relevant to the issue here:

- http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general?query=datalabel

But with a fixed width and dynamic number of columns, you're going to have a variety of problems.

Comment: Hi The X coordinate of  line needs to be at the starting point of X Axis (see my image). How can that be achieved? in your example, the line won't start from there?

Comment: I am not trying to draw a random line. I want to display the Y axis. As in my jsfiddle example, the Y axis only shows value and I want to show line as well.

Comment: see edited answer. Not sure what you mean by showing the yaxis only/show values/show line, etc.

Comment: Hi, I updated the question with a new attached image. Hopefully you can see what I mean now.