# data labels overlapping each other in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

data labels overlapping is a tricky problem when areas of the chart are crowded.
Let's look here: http://jsfiddle.net/zpd88mt7/1/

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="container" class="chart_container" style="width:800px; height:400px;"></div>
</body>
```

JS

```
var chart_options = {
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'scatter',
    zoomType: 'xy'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        align: 'center',
        rotation: 0,
        x: 0,
        y: -2,
        formatter: function() {
          return this.point.name;
        }
      },
      marker: {symbol: 'circle'}
    }              
  },
  series: [
    {
      id: 'volumes',
      lineWidth: 0,
      index: 10,
      marker: {
        enabled: true,
        radius: 4
      },
      data: [
        {x: 6798, y: 770, name: '01-XXXXXXXXX', id: '01'},
        {x: 7934, y: 1350, name: '02-XXXXXXXXX', id: '02'},
        {x: 7516, y: 926, name: '03-XXXXXXXXX', id: '03'},
        {x: 7143, y: 907, name: '04-XXXXXXXXX', id: '04'},
        {x: 7741, y: 1188, name: '05-XXXXXXXXX', id: '05'},
        {x: 3449, y: 1121, name: '06-XXXXXXXXX', id: '06'},
        {x: 7542, y: 917, name: '07-XXXXXXXXX', id: '07'},
        {x: 8634, y: 1124, name: '08-XXXXXXXXX', id: '08'},
        {x: 7986, y: 1132, name: '09-XXXXXXXXX', id: '09'},
        {x: 9311, y: 1261, name: '10-XXXXXXXXX', id: '10'},
        {x: 7681, y: 552, name: '11-XXXXXXXXX', id: '11'},
        {x: 7665, y: 1148, name: '12-XXXXXXXXX', id: '12'},
        {x: 8024, y: 889, name: '13-XXXXXXXXX', id: '13'},
        {x: 8882, y: 1278, name: '14-XXXXXXXXX', id: '14'},
        {x: 7164, y: 1015, name: '15-XXXXXXXXX', id: '15'}
      ]
    }
  ]
}

var chart;
$(function() {
      chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chart_options);
  }
);
```

A good solution could be iterating on labels and moving them upward (or elsewhere) in a free nearby position and connect them to their dot with a line. But it looks like something needing a good amount of time and effort.

Do you know if this has already been solved?

Maybe Highcharts developers are planning something on this side? Probably this is affecting many Highcharts users.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20050449/2732991). Might be what you need.