# HighChart Stacked Column label issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, label, jsfiddle

I have a chart with values that are uneven, ie: First value is 1315 and second value is 1, and so on, and when displaying the chart the labels are being overlapped. I have already searched in multiple forums but no one had the exact same problem. Here's a fiddle to see the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/6LutjLc3/

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Stacked column chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Issue']
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumption'
        },
        stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        align: 'right',
        x: -30,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 25,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
        borderColor: '#CCC',
        borderWidth: 1,
        shadow: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
                this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
                'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                style: {
                    textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [1235]
    }, {
        name: 'Toto',
        data: [2]
    }, {
        name: 'Matt',
        data: [1]
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [72]
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [3]
    }]
});
```

});

What I need to code is to give the value 1 one box where the label fits in as like any other example in highchart.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure what you are expecting. When you "like any other..." you mean that the series would be large enough to fit the datalabel inside it? The only way to do that is to make the chart large enough, or falsify the data to make the series larger. Neither sounds like a good idea.  I have to imagine that if this is the problem you are having, there are better ways to go about visualizing your data...

Comment: I would suggest, for example, not using a stacked chart, but a normal bar chart.

Comment: Yes that's what i meant. I have already suggested another chart format but the client wants that specifically.

Comment: Then again, the question is what do you actually want here? To make the data point large enough to fit the label means either making the chart much larger to spread the data, or setting a minimum size for the data point that distorts the data to a great extent, or not allowing values so small...

Comment: Just to be on the same page: Highcharts library doesn't provide logic to prevent dataLabel from overlapping. You can try to write your own logic for that: http://jsfiddle.net/menXU/1/ (works for two series). [Similar topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044479/highcharts-spline-datalabels-overlaping/20050449).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your client demands use of this style of graph you can get better looking results by modifying your dataLabel settings. Setting overflow to false and adding a formatter function that only returns a value if it's let's say at least 7% (or whatever percentage works best for you) of the current total will help. See the following:

```js
dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    overflow: false,
    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
    style: {
        textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
    },
    formatter: function () {        
        if (this.percentage >= 7) return this.y;
    }
}
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/6LutjLc3/4/

Comment: This solved my problem. Not just what I wanted to do, but it was enough for my client. Thanks a lot! Sry the delay to mark your response as the accepted answer.

Comment: No prob, glad it helped!